# Cast Varchar to Decimal with Thousand Separator Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, casting

Today I am wondering why these simple sql statement returned error instead of successfully executed:

```
GO
SELECT CAST('1,234.00' AS DECIMAL(22,2))
GO
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(22,2), '1,234.00')
```

If I remove the thousand separator, I find that the script executed successfully.

```
GO
SELECT CAST('1234.00' AS DECIMAL(22,2))
GO
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(22,2), '1234.00')
```

So the question is why sql server does not accept thousand separator as input?

Furthermore and out of topic, I find that the same logic executed successfully in C#.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s = "1,234.00";
    Console.WriteLine(decimal.Parse(s)); // result 1234.00
}
```

Why they having different policy for casting object? I have validated the string at C#, and the validation works well. However when I load the string into sql server, I get the error.

Comment: I don't know about SQL but parsing decimals and floats in C# without any additional parameters like format or CultureInfo depends entirely on your system's regional settings.

Comment: Correct, the regional setting is same, comma for thousand separator and point for decimal separator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try converting via money instead.

```
declare @d decimal(10,2)
SELECT @d = CAST('1,234.00' AS money)
select @d
GO
SELECT CONVERT(money, '1,234.00')
```

will give

```
1234.00
1234.00
```

Similarly

```
declare @m money = 1234
select CONVERT(varchar(20), @m, 1)
```

gives

```
1,234.00
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: By far this is the simplest solution and now I wonder why they has different logic for decimal and money.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server's CONVERT is not as versatile as .net's `Parse`.

- If you use an SQL Server version prior to 2012, you might have to manually remove the thousands separators (using [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)).
- Starting with SQL Server 2012, you can use the [PARSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213316.aspx) method, which seems to use the .net methods internally. In particular, when converting to `decimal`, it uses [`NumberStyles.Number`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx), which includes `AllowThousands`. The following statement will return the correct value:

  ```
  SELECT PARSE('1,234.00' AS decimal(22,2) USING 'en-us')
  ```

Comment: Actually, it is a question why the sql cast is not the same as dot net's. Moreover, it happened for a such simple / standard conversion rule.

Comment: @Fendy: The SQL CAST/CONVERT statement is much older than the .NET framework (even the SQL Server versions in the 90s had it, IIRC). I guess they didn't want to break backwards compatibility by changing the behaviour of such a fundamental T-SQL statement.

Comment: It makes sense now it is an old feature. However, I don't think it will give problem when improving the decimal conversion in future releases (2k, 2k5, etc). I believe it won't break compatibility since it just `weakens the precondition` (sorry, LSP a little bit). Now it doesn't makes sense why they don't improve it.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, decimal cant use thousands separators. The best solution for you is to convert to money and then convert to decimal.

```
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(22,2), CONVERT(money, '1,234.00'))
```

or simpler for only money

```
SELECT CONVERT(money, '1,234.00')
```